# When I Adding to [HttpPost] My Code Local Host Does Not Showing Frontend

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm trying to create a simple calculator but when i adding to [HttpPost] to the controller before IActionResult Calculator, it does not showing any response in browser. Without [HttpPost] i can see frontend part but i can't get any result for result. This is my controller code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new SimpleCalculatorModels());
        }

        public IActionResult Calculator(SimpleCalculatorModels model, string method)   
        {
            if (method == "addition")
            {
                model.ResultNumber = model.FirstNumber + model.SecondNumber;
            }
            if (method == "substraction")
            {
                model.ResultNumber = model.FirstNumber - model.SecondNumber;
            }
            if (method == "multiplication")
            {
                model.ResultNumber = model.FirstNumber * model.SecondNumber;
            }
            if (method == "division")
            {
                model.ResultNumber = model.FirstNumber / model.SecondNumber;
            }

            return View(model);
        }

    }
}
```

And this is my View class:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.SimpleCalculatorModels
@{

}


<body>
    <h2>SIMPLE CALCULATOR</h2>
    <div class = "border-dark">
       
           <div class = "form-group">
             <label for = "FirstNumber">First Number</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstNumber" name="FirstNumber" value="@Model.FirstNumber"/> 
           </div>

           <div class = "form-group">
             <label for = "SecondNumber">Second Number</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SecondNumber" name="SecondNumber" value="@Model.SecondNumber"/> 
           </div>

           <button type= "submit" class="btn-btn-info" id="addition" value="addition" name="calculate">+</button>
           <button type= "submit" class="btn-btn-danger" id="substraction" value="substraction" name="calculate">-</button>
           <button type= "submit" class="btn-btn-warning" id="multiplication" value="multiplication" name="calculate">*</button>
           <button type= "submit" class="btn-btn-default" id="division" value="division" name="calculate">/</button>

            <div class = "form-group">
             <label for = "Result">Result</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ResultNumber" name="ResultNumber" value="@Model.ResultNumber"/> 
           </div>



    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: HI@XcellentEEE , Do you mean when you add [httppost] on your `Calculator` action, you can't find your page?

Comment: Hi @Xinran Shen, Yes i can't get any .cshtml page when add [httppost], without [httppost] i can see index page but my calculator does not work when i trying to take output. I can just writing numbers, there is no output.

Comment: The View class you provided is `index.cshtml` right?

Comment: View class name is `Calculator.cshtml`. When i add view to `Index.cshtml` it didn't work. Actually my .cshtml code does not showing class types too. For example, i wrote btn-btn-info but btn is same with others.

Comment: If your view is `Calculator.cshtml` you also need a [httpget] action to load it. But if you wanna show this view in `index.cshtml` and `Calculator` action just do some calculations and return the result, you need to modify your code a bit. I will write an asnwer to show this situation.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm waiting for your answer. I add both [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] above the `Calculator` class but it has problem with response. For example, i write 5 for first number, 4 for secon number and clicking '+' button. It does not showing any response in result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model**

```
public class SimpleCalculatorModels
{
    public SimpleCalculatorModels()
    {
        FirstNumber = 0;
        SecondNumber = 0;
        ResultNumber = 0;

    }
    public double SecondNumber { get; set; }
    
    public double FirstNumber { get; set; }

    public double ResultNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }


    public IActionResult Index(SimpleCalculatorModels model)
    {
        return View(model); 
    }
    
    
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Calculator(SimpleCalculatorModels model,string method)
    {
        if (method == "addition")
        {
            model.ResultNumber = model.FirstNumber + model.SecondNumber;
        }
        if (method == "substraction")
        {
            model.ResultNumber = model.FirstNumber - model.SecondNumber;
        }
        if (method == "multiplication")
        {
            model.ResultNumber = model.FirstNumber * model.SecondNumber;
        }
        if (method == "division")
        {
            model.ResultNumber = model.FirstNumber / model.SecondNumber;
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", model);
    }


}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model SimpleCalculatorModels

<h2>SIMPLE CALCULATOR</h2>
<form asp-action="Calculator" method="post">

    <div class = "border-dark">

               <div class = "form-group">
                 <label for = "FirstNumber">First Number</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstNumber" name="FirstNumber" value="@Model.FirstNumber"/>
               </div>

               <div class = "form-group">
                 <label for = "SecondNumber">Second Number</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SecondNumber" name="SecondNumber" value="@Model.SecondNumber"/>
               </div>

               <button type= "submit" class="btn-btn-info" id="addition" value="addition" name="method">+</button>
               <button type= "submit" class="btn-btn-danger" id="substraction" value="substraction" name="method">-</button>
               <button type= "submit" class="btn-btn-warning" id="multiplication" value="multiplication" name="method">*</button>
               <button type= "submit" class="btn-btn-default" id="division" value="division" name="method">/</button>

                <div class = "form-group">
                 <label for = "Result">Result</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ResultNumber" name="ResultNumber" value="@Model.ResultNumber"/>
               </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

**Demo**

[image]

**Updated=========================================**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

  //other actions

   //this get action will load the Calculator.cshtml page
    public IActionResult Calculator(SimpleCalculatorModels model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    
    //this post action will do some calculations and return the value 
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Calculator(SimpleCalculatorModels model,string method)
    {
        if (method == "addition")
        {
            model.ResultNumber = model.FirstNumber + model.SecondNumber;
        }
        if (method == "substraction")
        {
            model.ResultNumber = model.FirstNumber - model.SecondNumber;
        }
        if (method == "multiplication")
        {
            model.ResultNumber = model.FirstNumber * model.SecondNumber;
        }
        if (method == "division")
        {
            model.ResultNumber = model.FirstNumber / model.SecondNumber;
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**Calculator.cshtml**

Same as the `index.cshtml` i provided.

Comment: .cshtml file added to Calculator, am i right?

Comment: sorry, I don't get your point. In this demo, I don't create any `Calculator.cshtml`, In controller, I use `index` action to load this page and `Calculator` action to do some calculations and return reuslt to `index` action.

Comment: I'm still on trouble, i really don't understand i'm just copied what you do but it didn't work in my project (:. program.cs can be reason of that?

Comment: Hi @XcellentEEE, Because i see you  initialize model in index action, So i misunderstand you craete this VIew in `index.cshtml`, Now i have updated my answer, You can reder to it, then you can do calculations in `Calculator.cshtml`

Comment: Hi @Xinran Shen, now it worked thank you so much. I can just accept answer, i can't give upvote because of my reputation sorry for that.

Comment: Don't care about it ,I'm glad to see you solved the problem